# How to load child data to view based on parent id after Parent data load?

Tags: react-native

First I load data from API to FlatList. once data load, I need to append 3 data to every each main data based on their id.

For example, I have list of users details. every users have multiple photos.
so, What I want is first I need to load list of data. then I need to append images under each user details. I can get those photos from separate API based on user id.
I know, that I can join table and get both details together from API. but, I don't want to do that.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getListOfUsers();
  };

  getListOfUsers= () => {
    const { page } = this.state;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
      API.get(`/users?page=${this.state.page}`)
      .then(res => res.data.users.data)
      .then((responseJson)=> {
        this.setState({
          data: page === 1 ? responseJson : [...this.state.data, ...responseJson],
          error: responseJson.error || null,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false
        })
      }).catch(error => {this.setState({ error, loading: false, refreshing: false });});
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
             data= {this.state.data}
             renderItem={({item}) =>
               <View>
                 <View>
                   <View>
                    <View style={styles.smallsizepro}>
                       // I need to append images here
                    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate component renderItem and call api there.

```
renderItem = ({item}) =>  <OtherComponent item={item} />

render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
             data= {this.state.data}
             renderItem={this.renderItem}
```

**OtherComponent.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserPhotos();
  };

getUserPhotos= () => {
    //api call and set those data in the state.
}


  render() {
    return (
        <View>
             <View>
                 <View>
                     <View style={styles.smallsizepro}>
                       // I need to append images here
                     </View>
```

Comment: you can improve this answer